# Create a 7 quest. & answer Alexa skill

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create a skill that allows a user to answer questions within a skill.  Here's the flow...

Alexa open 'skill'

Alexa: How many planets are in the solar system?

User:

Code: collect response and store to a db

Alex:  ask Question 2

User:

Code:  collect response and store to a db.

I'm stuck on how to collect the answer (the voice response) from the user and then move to the next question in the queue?   I do know how to save records to a db.

Does anyone know of any good examples i can follow?

Answer (score 0):

For each of the pieces of data that you want the user to supply, you should set those up as a "slot".  Use the new skill builder tool to set up the intent, the slots that go with it, and the prompts for those slots.

You can then "delegate" the dialog to Alexa who will prompt the user for each slot value in turn, and you'll get a request to your skill code with all the slots populated once she is done.  There's detailed documentation here which I hope will help https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/dialog-interface-reference but for me, once I understood that I needed a slot per answer, I was able to follow the documentation and get my skill working.

Comment: do you have an example.  i'm struggling on this.  in addition, what if i have two questions where the answers are the same - I'm not seeing how that is handled.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the answers are the same, they should end up in a slot per answer.  I did blog a little bit about this but it's only using a single slot so I don't know if it will help - see here https://lornajane.net/posts/2017/building-conversations-with-alexa